# TypeError: _e$relatedTarget.closest is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a custom input where on blur I am using next focused element using event.relatedTarget which is working fine

```
e.target.closest(".input-container") !== e.relatedTarget?.closest(".input-container")
```

Now for testing I am using React Testing library with Jest . In which if I use

```
 const input = screen.getByLabelText("Content URL");
 input.blur();
```

This is giving me following error

```
TypeError: _e$relatedTarget.closest is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think RTL
input.blur does not support relatedTarget till now as it is not allowing any params. So I went back to good old "fireEvent"

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent, { specialChars, TargetElement } from "@testing-library/user-event";

 userEvent.type(input, "");
 // input.blur(); 
 fireEvent.blur(input, { relatedTarget: null})
```

Now not getting any errors.